# How to redirect /wp-admin page to another page (not wp-login.php) in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can I redirect `example-site.com/wp-admin` to another page?

I delete wp-login.php and made another login page, but now if I visit /wp-admin it redirects to `https://www.example-site/wp-login.php`?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example-site%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

How I make a redirect to other page (404 or other white page)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128838/redirect-wp-login-php-to-another-page

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want redirect only /wp-admin to other page not wp-login.php. For example if user open example-site.com/wp-admin he was redirect to example-site.com  (homepage)

Answer (score 2):

```
function custom_redirect(){

    $get_view = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // Replace link with your login page link
    $custom_login  = home_url(); 
    if( $get_view == "wp-admin" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    {
       wp_redirect($custom_login);
    }
   }

   add_action('init','custom_redirect');
```

Add this code to your functions.php file

Comment: I try to use this code but not work for my problem. For example if user open example-site.com/wp-admin he was redirect to example-site.com (homepage)

Comment: I edited code, now function redirects wp-admin to home.. @tecn603

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful plugin that does exactly what you're looking for:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/

In the settings area (Side Admin Menu --> Settings --> General --> all the way to the bottom of the page, choose your preferred login url and "404" for the error page.

For instance, instead of going to "https://example.com/wp-login.php",
you can log in at "https://example.com/secret-entrance".

In order to keep it hidden, remember to remove the "meta" sidebar widget so people can't determine your secret login.